# Como evitar que um método imprima dados ao chamar uma API de terceiros?

Tags: php, api

Estou usando uma API e em alguns casos um recurso dela imprime na tela quando há erros (erros da api, não PHP). Acontece que eu chamo essa API via AJAX e isso quebra meu código já que a requisição acaba gerando um JSON inválido.

Existe alguma maneira de evitar isso em PHP? Por exemplo, de um determinado trecho do código até outro trecho, que nada seja impresso na tela?

Algo assim:

```php
// desativaria impressão de qualquer coisa aqui
$this->soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdlLink);
$retorno = $this->soapClient->testFunction($params);
// ativaria impressão aqui
```

No caso acima quando chamo testFunction, em vez de guardar o erro na variável $retorno, ele imprime na tela.

Quando se acessa um recurso SOAP você está chamando uma função preestabelecida pelo desenvolvedor da API SOAP. Acontece que algumas vezes testFunction imprime o erro direto e não como retorno da chamada.

O que fazer para resolver esse problema?

Comment: **Só para ficar de alerta: esta pergunta não tem nada a ver com SOAP nem com captura de erros ou exceções.**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Você pode usar o [Output Buffer](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.outcontrol.php) do PHP para capturar a saída sem enviar para o cliente:

```php
ob_start(); 
$this->soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdlLink);
$retorno = $this->soapClient->testFunction($params);
$output_retido = ob_get_contents(); //opcional, caso queira usar o que foi retido
ob_end_clean();
```

Comment: Obrigado Bacco. Funcionou como eu queria.

Answer (score 4):

Tem uma gambiarra para inibir a impressão de erros no próprio *core* do PHP, que é usar o [operador de controle de erros `@`](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) antes do comando:

```php
$retorno = @$this->soapClient->testFunction($params);
```

Comment: testFunction é um recurso da API via Soap. Se o desenvolvedor da API quer imprimir vai acabar aparecendo na minha requisição ajax. Não é erro do PHP.

Comment: Como assim? Se você diz que "em vez de guardar o erro na variável $retorno, ele imprime na tela", o erro seria do php. Pode esclarecer isso?

Comment: Você chegou a testar minha sugestão? Pelo que você está dizendo, o `@` deve sim suprimir o erro. @rodrigoum

Answer (score 3):

Utlizando [display_errors](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) é possivel ocultar/exibir os erros em tempo de execução em um script especifico.

```
ini_set('display_errors', false);
$this->soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdlLink);
$retorno = $this->soapClient->testFunction($params);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
```

Comment: Não é erro do PHP. É um erro que a própria API manda.